# AndroidStudio play button: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android

I was building my app through Android Studio normally. After 2 or rebuilds (through play button) I've faced this error: `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES`

Suddenly this happens with Android Studio opened.... How is that possible?

Tried to follow forum's instructions but none worked...
Tried to change dependency to:
        `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'`

Also didn't work

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
```

Ive saw that creating new app from the start the same error appears
Im using this version of JAVA

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.33+15-CA (build 11.0.4+11-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.33+15-CA (build 11.0.4+11-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was happening because I used an USB extension!
Connecting directly on the PC with the cable solved the issue... crazy solution but I hope it find someone with same issue